# Spring suddenly has cyclic dependencies after switching to new version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

A maven project has spring-boot-starter-parent as its parent. I just switched the version from 2.3.1.RELEASE to 2.6.7.

Suddenly, the springboot application that uses this project has cyclic dependencies with this error:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  com.mycompany.spring.logging.configuration.InterceptorConfiguration (field com.mycompany.spring.logging.RequestInterceptor com.mycompany.spring.logging.configuration.InterceptorConfiguration.interceptor)
└─────┘


Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.
```

No Java source has changed, no other dependencies have changed. The classes in the error (InterceptorConfiguration and RequestInterceptor) are in another internal library and they have not changed.

I'm a bit confused about what's causing the circular reference, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Setting `spring.main.allow-circular-references=true` seems like a less-than-ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation,
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6.0-M2-Release-Notes#circular-references-prohibited-by-default, Circular references are not prohibited by default. Circular references can be allowed again by setting `spring.main.allow-circular-references` to `true`

So, there are chances that your application had circular dependency earlier as well but was working as Spring allowed it by default. Best solution is to identify and remove the circular references.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess if I can prove that we had a circular reference before, no one on the team will object to setting `allow-circular-references` (it _sounds_ bad and some other people objected). Or... restrict the upgrade to spring-boot 2.5.x lol :P

Comment: Then checkout the old version before upgrade, set `allow-circular-references` to `false` :)

Comment: Further investigation suggests those circular references _were_ there before, we just didn't notice. So I've set `allow-circular-references` to true for now, and opened a new issue to remove them properly.

Comment: How did you remove them properly?

Answer (score 0):

setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true doesn't work while starting the application.

Try Adding @Lazy annotation on InterceptorConfiguration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).